# PyQt app doesn't exit when i close the window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, spyder

Whenever i execute the code and close the window, it closes,but the python console in the IDE doesn't return the exit code,when i try to run it again i get a warning dialog that says something like

```
No python console is selected to run main.py
```

So i have to close the IDE python console, and open a new one, then run the program in the new python console

I'm using spyder IDE 64 bits on windows

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()       
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ummuu? this code is work fine for me . Ubuntu 12, Spyder 2.1.9, Python 2.7.3, Qt 4.8.1, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.9.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you execute the code in a running (i)python console, you do not need to start a qapplication in the usual way, the two lines

```
win = QMainWindow()       
win.show()
```

will be enough to get you running. This is because the console already has a (threaded) qapplication prepared for you.

The error message can be caused when no console has focus (i.e., perhaps the one you were using quit because of `sys.exit()`, or you clicked away etc). You need to simply click in an (i)python console to get it to be 'selected', and then the run button should work again.