# Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, spyder

My problem is that when I'm using Spyder, code that was working fine before I had to re-install Spyder now requires me to re-start Spyder (quitting Python x,y, too) every time I run it.

I thought I had this solved yesterday, but for some reason today my problem has returned.

Someone suggested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412263/pyqt-app-doesnt-exit-when-i-close-the-window/25435316#25435316) yesterday, and it worked...momentarily.

I have tried:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class CompiledWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
......

cw = CompiledWindow()
cw.show()
```

The error I get is:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

Then I went back to this (same as before the dots)

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
cw = CompiledWindow()
cw.show()
```

Now it runs fine the FIRST time I run it and the second time, I get the same error as before. The third time, it tells me I don't have a shell selected.

I really don't fundamentally understand what it's complaining about. If I must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice, why does it run OK the first time? Clearly, it's happening the first time. Why do subsequent runs give me errors? Also, When I got rid of the app part as suggested in the linked answer, it worked...until this morning.

---

ETA This is a minimal working example as requested. Thanks!

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class CompiledWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Enter data below to generate report')
        names = ['Name Report', 'Open Logo Picture']
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        self.report_title_ask = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.rt = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.rt.setText(names[0])
        grid.addWidget(self.report_title_ask, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.rt, 0, 0)

        self.Logo_button = QtGui.QPushButton(names[1], self)
        self.LogoLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.Logo_button.clicked.connect(self.logo_pic)
        grid.addWidget(self.Logo_button, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.LogoLabel, 1,1)

        self.done_button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.done_button.setText('Click this when all data is entered')
        self.done_button.clicked.connect(self.finish_input_click)
        grid.addWidget(self.done_button, 2,1)        

    def rt_button_click(self):
        self.report_title = self.report_title_ask.text()

    def logo_pic(self):
        self.Logo_picture = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
        self.LogoLabel.setText(self.Logo_picture)

    def finish_input_click(self):
        self.report_title = self.report_title_ask.text()
        self.close()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
cw = CompiledWindow()
cw.show()
```

Comment: Could you post a stripped down but fully working example of the code you're trying to develop?

Comment: Added. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: For a GUI, you don't really want to "run" this from within the ipython console within spyder. Although you can define and execute window classes (as my previous answer), these are handled by the event loop that also runs the ipython console, causing potential conflicts. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to use to run settings (F6 for me) and select "execute in new dedicated python console". You'll need the qapplication back in that case. For what it's worth, I don't have problems running your minimal version from spyder's ipython, so could have something else going wrong.